# Remove the background color of <sup> in Edge browser

Tags: html, css

I am facing a weird issue in Edge and iOS browsers. There is some purple background is coming for  element. CSS background-color: none is not working.

Please let me know if anyone of you faced the issue.

```css
sup {
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<sup>Test</sup>
```

[image]

Comment: [mre], please, not screenshots. [ask].

Comment: @Kiran, can you add an example with the CSS of the actual part you show in the screen shot (label-heading for example). The snippet does not show your issue

Comment: I tested your snippet in Edge 80 on Windows 10. No issues there. In which version of Edge are you seeing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in lasted edge browser and your code working fine anyhow

Try to use `background-color` or `background` in `rgba'

```css
sup {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

```html
<sup>Test</sup>
```